# How to Change CurrentCulture in ASP.net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, localization

Multilingual App calls my APIs,i want to return messages,based on application language not based on app culture.So i decide to use Localization but Current Culture won't change with this code.
Something like this :

```
[HttpPost("[action]/{languageid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> login([FromBody] AccountViewModel model, [FromRoute] int languageid)
{
    var result = await signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, true);
    CultureInfo cultureInfo;
    if(languageid == 1)
    {
        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
    }
    else
    {
        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    }
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    if (result)
        return Ok(new {Result = true , Message = _localize["Login-Success"] });

    return Ok(new { Result = false, Message = _localize["Login-failed"] });

}
```

is there any better solution for returning multilingual message based on app language? i don't want save this message in my database.

Answer (score 1):

The Culture must be set for each request. Your login code does not save the setting anywhere so the setting is lost for the next webpage request.

ASP.NET Core has a framework for Localization which includes middleware to change the request culture.

[See the documentation for changing request culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request)

In your case you could use the `CookieRequestCultureProvider` to set a cookie when the user logins in that has their preferred culture and UI culture.

e.g.

```
this.Response.Cookies.Append(
   CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName, 
   "c=fa-IR|uic=fa-IR");
```

Make sure to use `CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName` for the cookie name as this is the name the middleware will look for.

There are other ways to set the request culture like `QueryStringRequestCultureProvider` or a `CustomProvider` if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but i need something like that to set culture in each request.
or create message table(json or xml file) inside my project not in database.any idea?